# How to show error 404 if someone mess with the URL DIrectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

htaccess and database conneciton pretty successfully

if someone typed `www.example.com/dsadsada` it showed an error page
if someone typed `www.example.com/news/dsadsa` it's also showed an error page
but when someone typed `www.example.com/news/besthotelinthearea2019/dsadsadsadsa` it doesn't showed an error page, it still displaying the best hotel in the area 2019 news but with no css, how can redirect it to 404 error ?
Thank you very much

and this is currently the code that is on my `.htaccess`

```
    RewriteEngine on

    ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
    ErrorDocument 300 /error.php

    RewriteRule ^index.html$ / [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] 

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^news/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) news.php?url=$1 [NC,L]

    RewriteRule ^sectioncategory/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) sectioncategory.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Well, the answer obviously is that you implement a rewrite to the error document, or, making much more sense, a rule that redirects the browser to the valid URL. So what is your _real_ question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^news/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) news.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
> ```

Because this rule/regex only grabs the part of the URL upto the second slash and discards the rest (potentially causing a duplicate content issue and opening your site up to abuse). eg. When you request `/news/besthotelinthearea2019/dsadsadsadsa` it is rewriting the request to `news.php?url=besthotelinthearea2019` (the `/dsadsadsadsa` part is effectively ignored). The same as if you had requested `/news/besthotelinthearea2019`.

Add an end-of-string anchor (`$`) to the regex so it only matches `/news/besthotelinthearea2019` and not `/news/besthotelinthearea2019/<anything>`.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ news.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

The same "problem" applies to your last rule (ie. "sectioncategory") as well.

NB: The `NC` flag should be unnecessary here (unless `news` can be requested with mixed case - not advisable) and the character class can be simplified. For example, the above is equivalent to:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([\w-]+)$ news.php?url=$1 [L]
```

The shorthand character class `\w` is the same as `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`.

---

*Aside:*

> if someone typed `www.example.com/news/dsadsa` it's also showed an error page

In this case, the "error page" must be generated by your script (`news.php`), not Apache.

(Whereas the URL in the first part of this answer will now trigger the Apache `ErrorDocument`, since it does not match your rule.)

Comment: the $ sign worked wonderfully, thanks MrWhite. Bless You !